# Simple Regex for multiple matches on single line and text between them

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I have the following text

> [fr-FR] C'est la francais![en] This is english.[es-ES] Spain

and more complex example:

> [ad-sad]asd.,/?|":{{}[a!@#$%^&()**d [en]aedasd;

It's like key-value based pairs, but with culture around square brackets [] and the text after it. There is no stop symbol. Is it possible to take the culture as a group one `$1` and the text after it as a group 2 `$2`

| Group1 $1 | Group2 $2 |
| --- | --- |
| fr-FR | C'est la francais! |
| en | This is english. |
| es-ES | Spain |

And the second example:

| Group1 $1 | Group2 $2 |
| --- | --- |
| ad-sad | `asd.,/?|":{{}[a!@#$%^&()**d` |
| en | `aedasd;` |

Literally after the culture it may appear any character.
I've tried several approached lookahead/lookbehinde/positive/negative/nested grouping, but cannot figure it out how to make it.
I only managed to work to group 1: `(\[[\w-]+\])`
Also tried something like that: `(\[[\w-]+\])(?:(?!\[[\w-]+\]))` - didn't work.

The last solution that I could use is to work only with first groups and manually extract the text from the input using `C# code`, Each match has `index` and `length` which will save time traversing the whole input.

Comment: Maybe `Regex.Matches(text, @"\[([\w-]+)](.*?)(?=\[[\w-]+]|$)")`? See https://regex101.com/r/JucUdq/1

Comment: A more strict case, you can use `(\[[a-z]{2,3}(?:-[a-z]{2,3})?\])((?:(?!\[[a-z]{2,3}(?:-[a-z]{2,3})?\]).)*)`. It ensures whatever is between `[` and `]` is 2-3 alphabetic characters followed by, optionally, `-` then 2-3 alphabetic characters. You can mix this with @WiktorStribiżew's regex above to your needs. This regex using the `i` (case-insensitive flag). See it here: https://regex101.com/r/f1PdWD/1

Comment: Thanks a lot, but you have to post it as an answer, so I can accept it. However I will test it with more cases tomorrow

Comment: Does this have to keep in mind that brackets might occur within the plain text sections? And if so, how can you be sure those will not be mistaken for a culture?

Comment: yes in the plain text could exists with `[va-Ra]` which could be some real value, but in that scenario it will be read as a culture, we have control to change the format of the how the culture is visualized, for example use `{}` instead `[]` , the same question is still valid , but in our case we don't expect such values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"\[([\w-]+)](.*?)(?=\[[\w-]+]|$)");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JucUdq/1).

*Details*:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([\w-]+)` - Group 1: one or more word or hyphen chars
- `]` - a `]` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars, other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\[[\w-]+]|$)` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there is either a sequence of `[` + one or more word or hyphen chars + `]`, or end of string.

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/EJaWr7):

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var s = "[ad-sad]asd.,/?|\":{{}[a!@#$%^&()**d [en]aedasd;";
        var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"\[([\w-]+)](.*?)(?=\[[\w-]+]|$)")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(x => new[] {x.Groups[1].Value, x.Groups[2].Value});
        foreach (var result in results) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{result[0]} => {result[1]}");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ad-sad => asd.,/?|":{{}[a!@#$%^&()**d 
en => aedasd;
```